# el menu no me ocupa el 100% del ancho de la pagina cuando esta en tamaño para celulares (css-html)

Tags: html, css, menú

```css
*{max-width: 2000PX;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: arial;
   }

body{
    background: #786767;

   }

header{
    width: 100%;
        height:90px;
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}

.container-header{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 2000px;
    position: relative;
    
    display: flex;
   
}
.container-logo-title{
    display: flex;
   
}

.container-logo-title img{
 width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-left: 10px;

margin-top:5px }

    

.container-logo-title h1
{
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-left: 10PX;
    font-size: 25px;
    
    
    
}
.container-menu{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
.menu ul{
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px; 
  
   
    

}
.menu ul li{
    list-style: none;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}


#check
{
display: none;}

.icon-menu
{display: none;}


.menu li  a {
padding: 15px;
position: left;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-size: 24px;

}
<--{efecto de ponerse en color rojo cuando pase el mouse }-->
.menu li  a:hover {background: #9D0B1D;
    border-radius: 20px;}
    


@media screen and (max-width:880px){
    .menu li  a {
padding: 20px;
 
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-size: 19px;

}
    .container-menu{
        position:absolute;
        align-content: center;
       
       
        
    }
    .menu {
      
        background: white;
        margin-top :88px;
        margin-right:0px;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 888;
        
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        
        z-index: 90000;
       
        
        
    }
    
    
    .container-logo-title img{
        
 
        margin-left: 0px;}}

    









@media screen and (max-width:888px)
    
{
    
    .container-logo-title H1
   {margin-top: 29px;
    font-size: 14;}
}
```

```html
<header>
    <DIV CLASS="container-header"> 
    <DIV CLASS= "container-logo-title">
<img src="imagenes/logo.jpg" class="img-logo">
    <H1>MELAMOBLAMIENTOS</H1></DIV>
 
     <input type="checkbox" id="check"  >
<label for="check" class="icon-menu"></label>

 
        <div class="container-menu">
<nav class= "menu">
    
<ul>
<li><a href="#Inicio">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="#Servicios">Servicios</a></li>
<li><a href="#Trabajos">Trabajos</a></li>
<li><a href="#Contacto">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
            </div>
        </DIV>
  </header>
```

Estoy haciendo un menu horizontal cuando esta en la computadora este en el top 0  al ostado del logo y el titulo,  pero  cuando este en tamaño para celulares este  abajo del logo y el titulo y ocupe todo el ancho de la pagina. el problema es que cuando esta en tamaño para celulares  no me ocupa el 100% del ancho .

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código para poder ver dónde puede estar el error? :)

Comment: Perdon crei que lo habia añadido . Listo  ya esta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que he probado, solo haría falta decirle que, cuando el tamaño sea el del móvil, el contenedor `.container-menu` debe ocupar el 100%, es decir, faltaría añadirle el tamaño del `width`:

```
  .container-menu{
    position:absolute;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Dejo todo el código con eso corregido para que se pueda comprobar mejor:

```css
* {
  max-width: 2000PX;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
}

body{
  background: #786767;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height:90px;
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}

.container-header{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 2000px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex; 
}

.container-logo-title{
  display: flex;
}

.container-logo-title img{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top:5px 
}



.container-logo-title h1{
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 23px;
  margin-left: 10PX;
  font-size: 25px; 
}

.container-menu{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.menu ul{
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px; 
}

.menu ul li{
  list-style: none;
  float:right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#check{
  display: none;
}

.icon-menu{ 
  display: none;  
}

.menu li  a {
  padding: 15px;
  position: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
}

/*efecto de ponerse en color rojo cuando pase el mouse */
.menu li  a:hover {
  background: #9D0B1D;
  border-radius: 20px;
}



@media screen and (max-width:880px){
  .menu li  a {
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 19px;
  }

  .container-menu{
    position:absolute;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .menu {
    background: white;
    margin-top :88px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 888;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 90000;
  }

  .container-logo-title img{
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:888px){
  .container-logo-title h1{ 
    margin-top: 29px;
    font-size: 14;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container-header"> 
  
  
    <div class= "container-logo-title">
      <img src="imagenes/logo.jpg" class="img-logo">
      <h1>MELAMOBLAMIENTOS</h1>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="check"  >
    <label for="check" class="icon-menu"></label>


    <div class="container-menu">
      <nav class= "menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#Inicio">Inicio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Servicios">Servicios</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Trabajos">Trabajos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Contacto">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: muchas gracias era un error tan basico  espero con la practica mejorar :)

Answer (score 0):

Proba con esto

```
.container-header{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

.container-logo-title h1{
    font-size: 21px;
}

.container-menu{
    position: absolute;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu ul{
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu ul li{
    list-style: none;
    float: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 880px){
    .menu{
        background: white;
        margin-top: 88px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        z-index: 90000;
    }

    .menu li a{
        padding: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
}
```